# Erro ao validar data no firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, validação

Estou tentando validar se já existe uma data ou não no banco. 
A situação que ocorre é a seguinte, possuo uma tela com um calendarview, ao selecionar uma data ela é exibida em um textview. Depois que a data foi escolhida, clico no botão agendar, com isso são inseridos o usuário, o recurso (selecionado em um spinner) e a data (selecionada no calendarview) no meu banco no firebase.
Porém, eu quero validar se a data selecionada, já existe no banco ou não. Se ela existir, exibirá uma mensagem que esta data não está disponível, se não existir agenda normalmente.
Mas, quando efetuo essa validação com o código abaixo, ocorre erro no android monitor e minha aplicação fecha. Alguém pode me ajudar? Abraços.
Segue código do android studio, banco de dados e o erro do android monitor.

```
package br.com.douglasprogtg.appcond;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import br.com.douglasprogtg.appcond.dao.Mensagem;
import br.com.douglasprogtg.appcond.dao.MensagemList;
import br.com.douglasprogtg.appcond.dao.Recurso;

public class AgendarRecursoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    String TAG = "AgendarRecursoActivity";
    String nomeRecurso;

    TextView txtData;
    CalendarView calendario;

    Recurso recurso;

    TextView txtNome;
    Button btnAgendarRecurso;
    Spinner recursoSpinner;

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_agendar_recurso);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        //databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        //.child("recursos").child(user.getUid()).child("");

        calendario = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarioRecurso);
        txtData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDataCalendario);
        txtNome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmailUsuarioRecurso);
        btnAgendarRecurso = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAgendarRecurso);
        recursoSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        txtNome.setText(user.getEmail());
        //txtData.setText("Data");

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        databaseReference.child("recursos").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                final List<String> recursoNome = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (DataSnapshot recursoSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //Pega título do nó
                    String recursoSnap = recursoSnapshot.getKey();

                    //Adiciona na lista
                    recursoNome.add(recursoSnap);
                }

                //Pega lista e poe no spinner
                ArrayAdapter<String> recursosAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AgendarRecursoActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, recursoNome);
                recursosAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                recursoSpinner.setAdapter(recursosAdapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        calendario.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                String date = dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year;
                Log.d(TAG, "onSelectedDayChange: " + date);

                txtData.setText(date);
            }
        });

        btnAgendarRecurso.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                recurso = new Recurso();
                recurso.setNomeUsuario(txtNome.getText().toString());
                recurso.setDataRecurso(txtData.getText().toString());
                recurso.setNomeRecurso(recursoSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

                DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                databaseReference.child("recursos").child(recursoSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            if(snapshot.child("dataRecurso").getValue().toString().equals(recurso.getDataRecurso())){  //error in android monitor is here

                                Toast.makeText(AgendarRecursoActivity.this, "Data indisponível", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                            else{

                                reservarRecurso();

                            }

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });



            }
        });
    }

    public void reservarRecurso(){

        databaseReference.child("recursos").child(recursoSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()).push().setValue(firebaseDatabase, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                //Problem with saving the data
                if (databaseError != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(AgendarRecursoActivity.this, "Erro ao agendar recurso! Data não disponível", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    //Data uploaded successfully on the server
                    databaseReference.child("nomeUsuario").setValue(txtNome.getText().toString());
                    databaseReference.child("dataRecurso").setValue(txtData.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(AgendarRecursoActivity.this, "Recurso agendado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    retornaTela();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void agendar(View v) {
        calendario = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarioRecurso);
        SimpleDateFormat formatoData = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String dataRecurso = formatoData.format(new Date(calendario.getDate()));

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        nomeRecurso = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    public void retornaTela(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

[image: Android monitor error]
[image: Database firebase]

Comment: O que tem na linha 132 exatamente?

Comment: @Zulian A seguinte linha de código
if(snapshot.child("dataRecurso").getValue().toString().equals(recurso.getDataRecurso())){

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema está relacionado a algum objeto nulo (NullPointerException), verifique os objetos que você faz '.toString()' no seu 'btnAgendarRecurso.setOnClickListener...' que provavelmente o problema vai estar ali....